# How do I change thumbnail titles in O365 SharePoint asset lib"

Tags: sharepoint-online, picture-library, thumbnail

I have an Asset Lib in SharePoint online with thousands of flower images. Currently the thumbnail shows the title of the photo, the type, and the dimensions. I need to change these titles pull from other image metadata fields instead.

I looked at this great post but I cannot seem to retrofit it to SharePoint online.[How to edit xslt for thumbnail view of Asset Library.?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77572/how-to-edit-xslt-for-thumbnail-view-of-asset-library)

(I am happy to pay for a solution).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can customize it using CSR : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21521.promoted-links-wrap-and-size-tiles-with-client-side-rendering.aspx

Note: if you are configure the apps on your share point application, you can find a lot of tiles apps on app store

Answer (score 0):

As best as I can tell, you will need to open up the Thumbnails.aspx file found in your asset library's "forms" folder. Use SPD.

Look for the webpart, .

Within this webpart you will need to find the attribute, GhostedXslLink="AssetPicker.xsl", change this to GhostedXslLink="".

You now need to add your custom XSL from the previous post to your webpart. Add a  property, and provide your xsl, similar to:

```
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart ...>
... other properties...
<xsl>
<!--add the customize xsl here from assetpicker.xsl-->
</xsl>
</WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
```

The MS reference for the XsltListViewWebPart may be found at:
[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataformwebpart.xsl.aspx]